Next.js + internationalisation - static website
I have a statically generated Next.js project (it's also a requirement that it remains static), which uses next-intl for localisation.
I want to improve SEO, so ideally I need dynamic Metadata. Since it's a static project, I cannot use generateMetadata. Is there a way for me to still have translated Metadata (depending on route path: /en, /fr, ...) without using server functions?
